# TRIGGER PostgresSQL, insert and delete

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Tengo 3 tablas, una "tarea" y otras dos tablas idénticas, con sus respectivos campos de nombre "imputa_pendientes" e "imputa". Las 3 tablas tienen de campo común id_proyecto.

Quiero conseguir que cuando se inserte una linea en tareas con id_secci=6, se copien las lineas que contengan ese id_proyecto de la linea insertada en tareas,  de la tabla "imputa_pendientes" a la tabla "imputa".

Aquí las tablas con sus columnas:

```
CREATE TABLE tar.tarea
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  id_proyecto integer NOT NULL,
  id_empleado_solicitante integer,
  id_empleado integer NOT NULL,
  id_secci integer NOT NULL,
  id_estado integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  semana date,
  fecha_entrega date,
  observaciones text,
  observaciones_entrega text,
  id_proto_periodo integer,
  revisada boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,

)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE tar.tarea
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE tar.tarea TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE tar.tarea TO public;


Tabla pro.imputa_pendiente;

CREATE TABLE pro.imputa_pendiente
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  insert_user_id oid,
  insert_fecha date,
  update_user_id oid,
  update_fecha date,
  id_proyecto integer,
  importe numeric(12,2),
  observaciones text,
  CONSTRAINT imputa_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT imputa_id_proyecto_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_proyecto)
      REFERENCES pro.proyecto (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE pro.imputa_pendiente
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE pro.imputa_pendiente TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE pro.imputa_pendiente TO public;


TABLA pro.imputa;

CREATE TABLE pro.imputa
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  insert_user_id oid,
  insert_fecha date,
  update_user_id oid,
  update_fecha date,
  id_proyecto integer,
  importe numeric(12,2),
  observaciones text,
  CONSTRAINT imputa_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT imputa_id_proyecto_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_proyecto)
      REFERENCES pro.proyecto (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE pro.imputa
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE pro.imputa TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE pro.imputa TO public;
```

Y he creado esta función, pero, no me copia las lineas de ese id_proyecto de imputa_pendiente a imputa si hay mas de una linea en imputa_pendiente con ese id_proyecto. En uno de los intentos, me ha copiado bien los valores, pero solo habiendo una linea en imputa_pendiente.

Aquí la función:

```
--DROP FUNCTION transladar_pendiente_imputado();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transladar_pendiente_imputado() RETURNS "trigger" AS $$
DECLARE
_id INTEGER;
_insert_user_id INTEGER;
_insert_fecha DATE;
_update_user_id INTEGER;
_update_fecha DATE;
_id_proyecto INTEGER;
_importe NUMERIC;
_observaciones VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    IF (tg_op = 'INSERT') THEN
        _id := NEW.id;
        _id_proyecto := NEW.id_proyecto;

    END IF;

    IF (NEW.id_secci= 6 ) THEN

            _insert_user_id := (SELECT insert_user_id FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = _id_proyecto);
            _insert_fecha := (SELECT insert_fecha FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = _id_proyecto);
            _update_user_id := (SELECT update_user_id FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = _id_proyecto);
            _update_fecha := (SELECT update_fecha FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = _id_proyecto);
            _importe := (SELECT importe FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = _id_proyecto);
            _observaciones := (SELECT observaciones FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = _id_proyecto);

            INSERT INTO pro.imputa(id, insert_user_id, insert_fecha, update_user_id, update_fecha, id_proyecto, importe, observaciones)
            VALUES (_id, _insert_user_id, _insert_fecha, _update_user_id, _update_fecha, _id_proyecto, _importe, _observaciones);

            DELETE FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = _id_proyecto; 
        RETURN NEW;

    ELSE
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; COMMENT ON FUNCTION transladar_pendiente_imputado() IS 'Copia los registros de imputado_pendiente a imputado del id_proyecto de la tarea pedidos id_secci=6';


--DROP TRIGGER transladar_pendiente;
CREATE TRIGGER transladar_pendiente
    AFTER INSERT ON tar.tarea
    FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE transladar_pendiente_imputado();
```

Si inserto una tarea con id_secci=6 (cuando imputa_pendiente tiene varias lineas con ese id_proyecto)

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (SELECT insert_user_id FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = _id_proyecto)"
PL/pgSQL function transladar_pendiente_imputado() line 20 at assignment

INSERT INTO tar.tarea_con_proyecto__vista (id_proyecto, revisada, semana, id_estado, id_secci, id_empleado_solicitante, id_empleado) VALUES ('2471', FALSE, '23/07/2018', '1', '6', '240', '240')
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (SELECT insert_user_id FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = _id_proyecto)"
PL/pgSQL function transladar_pendiente_imputado() line 20 at assignment
```

Alquien puede ayudarme? Gracias

Comment: no paso de este error si en imputa_pendiente hay mas de una linea con ese id_proyecto, si hay una unica linea si que lo realiza sin problemas. De error me dice lo siguiente:    ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (SELECT insert_user_id FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = _id_proyecto)"
PL/pgSQL function transladar_pendiente_imputado() line 20 at assignment

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver Qt Designer con esta pregunta?

Comment: El log de error que adjunto es el de Qt designer.

Comment: ¿Qt Designer? Qt Designer es una herramienta que sirve para crear GUI usando como base Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer que el trigger se ejecute solo cuando es insertado un registro con `id_secci = 6`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trasladar_pendiente 
  AFTER INSERT ON tar.tarea 
  FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.id_secci = 6) EXECUTE PROCEDURE trasladar_pendiente_imputado();
```

Y la función:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trasladar_pendiente_imputado() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO pro.imputa (id, insert_user_id, insert_fecha, update_user_id, update_fecha, id_proyecto, importe, observaciones)
   SELECT NEW.id, insert_user_id, insert_fecha, update_user_id, update_user_id, update_fecha, NEW.id_proyecto, importe, observaciones 
   FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = NEW.id_proyecto;

  DELETE FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = NEW.id_proyecto;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Puede que el problema que muestras en la publicación es debido a que la tabla `pro.imputa_pendiente` contiene más de un registro con el `id_proyecto`, lo que causa, al momento de asignar el resultado de la consulta a una variable, el error especificado. Asegúrate de que los datos son correctos.

En el caso de que es necesaria la existencia de múltiples registros con el mismo `id_proyecto` en la tabla `pro.imputa_pendiente` puedes añadir `LIMIT 1` a la consulta especificada, de tal manera que se selecciona un solo elemento. Esto, dependiendo del tipo de aplicación u orientación que tenga tu diseño de base de datos, puede que sea factible o no.

Comment: El problema no es en tarea, es en la tabla `pro.imputa_pendiente`, que es donde se están insertando los datos. Al parecer el registro que se intenta insertar ya existe allí.

Comment: Me daba error en calves duplicadas y he modificado tu codigo, eliminando un campo repetido en la consulta "update_user_id" y eliminadno el NEW de id. Voy a probar, parece que ya esta ;) ahora te comento.